# Adding markers in openseadragon viewer even if state variable is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openseadragon

I am adding markers on openseadragon viewer. This is the function I am using for this

```
if (cellLabeler) {
if (!viewer) return;
console.log("calling celllabel", cellLabeler);

viewer.addHandler("canvas-click", function (event) {
  const viewerPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(event.position);
  console.log("Clicking coordinates:", viewerPoint.x, viewerPoint.y);

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = { logo };
  viewer.addOverlay(img, viewerPoint);
});}
```

Celllabeler is a state variable I am using for toggling modes for adding markers. There is a button which toggles celllabeler state variable. It works when celllabeler is true, but it also works if I toggle it to false after labelling. Is this an issue with addHandler event that I am using?

EDIT: Code currently looks like this:

```
if (viewer){
console.log("calling celllabel", cellLabeler);

viewer.addHandler("canvas-click", function (event) {
  if (cellLabeler) {
    if (!viewer) return;
    const viewerPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(event.position);
    console.log("Clicking coordinates:", viewerPoint.x, viewerPoint.y);

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/10x10/000/11ff00";
    viewer.addOverlay(img, viewerPoint);
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done the addHandler, it'll always run regardless of the cellLabeler state. What you need to do is put the `if (cellLabeler)` inside the `addHandler`.

EDIT: here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
// Set up label mode buttons

var cellLabeler = false;

document.getElementById('start-labeling').addEventListener('click', function() {
  cellLabeler = true;
});

document.getElementById('stop-labeling').addEventListener('click', function() {
  cellLabeler = false;
});

// Set up OpenSeadragon

var viewer = OpenSeadragon( ... );

viewer.addHandler("canvas-click", function (event) {
  if (cellLabeler) {
    const viewerPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(event.position);
    console.log("Clicking coordinates:", viewerPoint.x, viewerPoint.y);

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/10x10/000/11ff00";
    viewer.addOverlay(img, viewerPoint);
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding if(cellLabeler) inside addHandler. What happens now is at first addHandler is called with celllabeler = false. And even after I toggle my button to labelling mode it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a problem with the scope of cellLabeler? Can you share what the code looks like now?

Comment: if (!viewer) return;
    console.log("calling celllabel", cellLabeler);

    viewer.addHandler("canvas-click", function (event) {
      if (cellLabeler) {
        if (!viewer) return;
        const viewerPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(event.position);
        console.log("Clicking coordinates:", viewerPoint.x, viewerPoint.y);

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/10x10/000/11ff00";
        viewer.addOverlay(img, viewerPoint);
      }
    });

Comment: That looks reasonable but I don't know the context outside of it. You should only be calling this code once, because you just want to add the handler once, and then it'll fire whenever there's a click. Is this code being run only once? If so, you probably don't need all of the !viewer checks.

Comment: I can probably remove the viewer checks at some places. But I have to run this code whenever I click on button to add labels ( that's why addlabeler checks ), so it is not going to be run once but multiple times whenever required.

Comment: You don't want to call `addHandler` multiple times... it's adding an event handler, and if you add multiple handlers for the same event, you're going to get weird results. The button should just turn on or off a flag that the handler checks.

Comment: So if i can't call addHandler multiple times, is there any other way on approaching this problem. A sample code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: You pass a function to addHandler that will get called multiple times. addHandler says "any time there's a click, please call this function". So you only need to say that once, because then the function will get called as many times as there are clicks. Does that make sense? If so, and you still feel you need to call addHandler more than once, can you explain why?

Comment: Hey @iangilman, you probably didn't understood why I need to call addHandler multiple times. What I trying to make is like a map where users can mark the locations according to their need. What I am doing right now is I have a button named "add Label" , when someone clicks on this button addLabeler variable becomes true and user can add labels freely on the map.

Comment: Now the problem is once addHandler event is called and even if I call button to "stop label" it keeps on working, whether I use the state variable inside addHandler event or outside addHandler. Also the user can click this button multiple times so this function will be called multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your scenario. I've added some sample code to this answer that hopefully shows how I would approach that scenario.